# The amount of items in the store Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning programming in Java, and I found one interesting example and solved it 80%. But there is this part that I don’t know exactly how to solve. I should enter an array indefinitely until I write "0" and then that array should break that array and add the sum of the numbers (but it is necessary that the decimals of the numbers are not limited, and the final sum at the end that is printed is rounded to 2 decimals .)
At the same time, I want to delete this part "Enter the number of purchased items: " where he asks how many items I will have, but only to enter without that part and stop collecting the sum.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumOfElementsOfAnArray {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Enter the number of purchased items: "); // I want to enter a array without this part
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      int size = s.nextInt();
      int myArray[] = new int [size];
      double sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter item prices (each separately) :  ");

      for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         myArray[i] = s.nextInt();
         sum = sum + myArray[i];
      }
 
      System.out.println("The total bill amount is:" +sum + "$");
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How not to print the line "Enter the number …"? Remove the statement from your code and it will not be executed (because it doesn't exist any longer). Can you provide an example input and expected output? What are the 20% that are not working?

Comment: With regards to the array you have two options (1) re-initialize/copy the array at each insert (this would solve your exact question) (2) use a `List<Integer>` instead.  With regards to your other question, you'll have to look at the other data types `float` and `double` if you want decimals.

Comment: I failed to do properly regarding decimals when I change I spoil everything and then the code doesn't work at all, and when I try to insert it it stops with 0. I delete the part where it asks me how many numbers to enter in the array. I just put it one by one and it stops at 0 and adds up but then it doesn't work for me so I don't know how to do it and fix it @knittl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with BigDecimal:

```
      BigDecimal myArray[] = new BigDecimal [size];
      BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
      System.out.println("Enter item prices (each separately) :  ");

      for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         myArray[i] = s.nextBigDecimal();
         sum = sum.add(myArray[i]);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use doble and System.out printf,
excample:

```
      double myArray[] = new double [size];
      double sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter item prices (each separately) :  ");

      for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         myArray[i] = s.nextDouble();
         sum = sum + myArray[i];
      }
      
      System.out.printf("The total bill amount is:%.2f$",sum);
```

Comment: NEVER use floating point (i.e. `double`) for financial calculations.

Comment: Looks ok but answer might lead OP to confusion about wrong usage of floating points. In financial calculations, BigDecimal should be preferred.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, it's my mistake. I forgot about it.